# BOOST_FOREACH iterating rvalue container has error with non const ref value

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using g++ 4.4.7 20120313

```
class obj { int a; }

std::list<obj> list;

BOOST_FOREACH(obj& v, list) { } // ok    
BOOST_FOREACH(const obj& v, list) { } // ok    

std::list<obj> getlist() { ... }

BOOST_FOREACH(obj& v, getlist()) { } // error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'obj&' from expression of type 'const obj'
BOOST_FOREACH(const obj& v, getlist()) {} // ok
```

why got error?
why should I use const obj& instead of obj& ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify to the following:

```
int f() { return 99 ; }
int main() {
    const int& p = f() ; // OK
    int& p = f() ;       // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference
                         // of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
    return 0 ;
}
```

Does this make more sense to you?

Comment: Especially the `return 0;` at the beginning );

Comment: @harmic: Whoops! Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

`getlist()` returns a temporary object. Normally, the temporary disappears (its lifetime is over) at the end of the expression it appears in. Temporaries can be bound to a const reference as a special-case in the standard, but not to a non-const reference.

To answer why, think of the implications of binding a temporary to a non-const reference: any changes made through the reference are going to be lost when the temporary's lifetime is over. By disallowing this, C++ is protecting you here.

Sutter covers this in [one of his older GOTWs](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Comment: thanks, but even if collection is temporary object, collection's item could have non-temporary object.
`list<shared_ptr<obj>> g_list;

list<shared_ptr<obj>> getlist() { return g_list; } // copy list<obj>, obj is shared.

BOOST_FOREACH(shared_ptr<obj>& v, getlist()) {
    // access v
}`
In this case, v is temporary object, but v's obj is not temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

```
BOOST_FOREACH(obj& v, getlist()) { }
```

Have you tried an rvalue reference?

```
BOOST_FOREACH(obj&& v, getlist()) { }
```

I recommend updating to at least g++ 4.6, then you can use the new range-based for loop in C++11:

```
for (obj&& v : getlist()) { }
```

Comment: Good, rvalue reference. I got it.

Comment: Oh, it's not working. const obj cannot be assigned to rvalue ref.